# Thread.Join() causing deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have three threads in total.  The first is the main UI thread, which starts a `System.Threading.Thread` (`ExperimentThread`), which in turn starts a `BackgroundWorker` (`WorkerThread`).

`MainThread` and `WorkerThread` both access a shared resource.  I synchronise access to this resource with the following object:

```
private static readonly Object LockObject = new Object();
```

which I use as follows in the main loop of each thread:

```
lock (LockObject)
{
    // Do something with shared resource here.
}
```

A cut-down version of `ExperimentThread` is as follows:

```
public void RunExperiment
{
    while (!bStopThread)
    {

        lock (LockObject)
        {
            // Do something with shared resource here.
        }

        if (bStopThread)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
}
```

And for completeness here is the DoWork method of `WorkerThread`:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker Worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    for (int X = 0; X < 200; X++)
    {
        if (Worker.CancellationPending)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }

        lock (LockObject)
        {
            // Do something with shared resource here.
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine when both threads are running freely.

At some point the UI thread will terminate the `ExperimentThread` by setting one of its boolean fields to true and then wait for it to end, as follows:

```
if (ExperimentThread.IsAlive)
{
    ExperimentThread.StopThread = true;
    ExperimentThread.Join();    // this line seems to cause the deadlock?
}
```

As soon as Join() is called, a deadlock occurs on the shared resource being accessed by `ExperimentThread` and `WorkerThread`, and my application hangs indefinitely.  This happens maybe 9 out of 10 times.

If I remove `ExperimentThread.Join()` from the code snippet above, the deadlock never occurs, and `ExperimentThread` appears to terminate gracefully (it then goes on to terminate `WorkerThread` by calling `CancelAsync()`).

Any ideas what could be the problem here?

(P.S. I've been using Console.WriteLine() to determine when locks are taken and released, which is what has lead me to believe there's a deadlock.  Is there a better to determine this, I could be wrong?)

Comment: Can you include the code executed by your `ExperimentThread`?

Comment: Not enough code shown here to determine the real cause...

Comment: 'Thread.Join() causing deadlock' - yup, that is just about the normal behaviour of Join(), or any other kind of hard-wait, in GUI app event-handlers.  I've seen deadlocked GUIs like this, in various languages, for decades, yet still we get 'You must wait for threads to terminate with Join/WaitFor/whatever' from stupid thread intro websites.  35 years of feeding inexperienced multithread developers the same crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better to determine this, I could be wrong?

A better way to check this is to use something like the [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx) available in higher level SKUs of Visual Studio.  It will allow you to see exactly what has locked each thread, and what handles threads are waiting on, etc.

As for the exact reason you are getting a deadlock - there isn't enough code to determine this, but common issues are:

1. `ExperimentThread` and the main thread (with the `Join()` call) are both locking on the same object - ie: within a `lock(LockObject)` statement.
2. `ExperimentThread` is using `Control.Invoke` to marshal a call back onto the UI thread.  Since the UI thread is blocked (waiting on the `Join()`), it can never process messages, which will prevent `ExperimentThread` from completing.

That being said, in general, I would recommend using `Task` or `Task<T>` instead of a new `Thread` if you're using .NET 4 or higher.  `Task` provides a much nicer API for working with threads, including allowing continuations instead of blocking.  C# 5 extends this to even allow you to asynchronously wait for the task to complete.

Comment: My BackgroundWorker is indeed using Control.Invoke to update something on the UI thread.  I think you have answered my question.  Many thanks and well deduced with the lack of code :-)

Comment: @digital_fate Yeah - calling `Invoke()` in a thread, and then calling `Join()` from the UI thread will cause a dead lock.

Comment: Other than removing the call to `Join()` I'm not sure how to proceed.  Either way, your answer is correct, shall I add something on the end of my question in order to explain what the problem was?

Comment: @digital_fate You could - there may be other approaches - why are you trying to block until the process is complete in the first place?  Are you using .NET 4 or higher?

Comment: The blocking call was in the code already with no hint as to why.  Without the blocking call it seems to work, but I suppose the `Invoke()` could feasibly happen after the UI thread has terminated, which wouldn't be too good. We're using .NET 2.o